# Can't find controls in FormView.InsertItemTemplate even on DataBound event

Tags: .net, asp.net, formview, findcontrol, databound

I have `FormView` in my page markup:

```
<asp:FormView ruanat="server" ID="FormView1" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" OnDataBinding="FormView1_DataBinding" OnDataBound="FormView1_DataBound">
   <InsertItemTemplate>
      <uc:UserControl1 runat="server" ID="ucUserControl1" />
   </InsertItemTemplate>
</asp:FormView>
<asp:SqlDataSource runat="server" ID="SqlDataSource1" SelectCommand="EXEC someSP" />
```

It's code-behind **WAS**:

```
protected void FormView1_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   var c = FormView1.FindControl("ucUserControl1"); // returns null
}
```

**BECAME**:

```
protected void FormView1_DataBinding(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   FormView1.ChangeMode(FormViewMode.Insert);
}

protected void FormView1_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   if (FormView1.CurrentMode = FormViewMode.Insert)
   {
      var c = FormView1.FindControl("ucUserControl1"); // returns null no more!
   }
}
```

In theory, I'm able to find control on `FormView` after it being data bound. But I'm not. Why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
If (FormView1.CurrentMode == FormViewMode.Insert)
      var c = FormView1.FindControl("ucUserControl1");
```

Comment: Can my update code be a workaround? Or where is the best place to change mode? `DataBiding`, `DataBound` ?